# Prove $f(x,y,z)=e^{iy+z}$ is continuous on $\mathbb R^3$.

Tags: complex-numbers, continuity

> Prove $f(x,y,z)=e^{iy+z}$ is continuous on $\mathbb R^3$.

I have already proved that other functions are continuous by using that $f, g$ are continuous implies $f+g$ and $fg$ are continuous.

However $f(x,y,z)=e^{iy+z}$ really bothers me. I know I can rewrite $f(x,y,z)=e^{iy+z}=e^z(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))$ but this doesn't help me much.

Comment: Isn't it just of $f(y,z)$, as $x$ doesn't appear in the LHS of your equation.

Comment: It is just to emphasize that the domain is $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Do you consider " $x \rightarrow e^{ix} $ is continous"  as granted?

Comment: Or consider "$ \sin x $ is continuous implies $i \sin x$ is continuous". ($g$ is continuous $\Rightarrow cg$ is continuous where $c$ is a constant.)

Comment: I guess I should consider $e^{ix}$, $sin(y)$ and $cos(y)$ as continuous. The exercise is an introductory exercise to the subject of continuity.

Answer (score 1):

You can show that this function is continuous by using the following facts about continuous functions:

- the projection maps $\pi_i : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, $(x_1, \dots, x_n) \mapsto x_i$ are continuous
- if $f$ is continuous, $cf$ is continuous for any scalar $c$
- if $f$ and $g$ are continuous, then $f + g$ is continuous
- if $f$ and $g$ are continuous, then $f\circ g$ is continuous

together with the fact that the map $\operatorname{exp} : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, $x \mapsto e^x$ is continuous.